# Is the test.dart package working

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I am trying to run a simple test copied from https://github.com/dart-lang/test/blob/master/README.md#asynchronous-tests

```
library epimss_reg.test;

import 'package:test/test.dart';
//import 'package:epimss_reg/epimss_reg.dart';

import "dart:async";


void main() {
  test("Stream.fromIterable() emits the values in the iterable", () {
    var stream = new Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3]);

    stream.listen(expectAsync((number) {
      print(number);
      expect(number, inInclusiveRange(1, 7));
    }, count: 3));
  });
}
```

When I run the app using as "Run as 'Dart Command-line Launch'" I get the following Console report

```
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:50888

00:00 [32m+0[0m: Stream.fromIterable() emits the values in the iterable[0m
1
2
3

00:00 [32m+1[0m: Stream.fromIterable() emits the values in the iterable[0m

00:00 [32m+1[0m: All tests passed![0m
```

Not that 'All test passed!' but how is this when the range should have been inclusiveRange(1, 3)?

Thanks

Comment: *"the range should have been inclusiveRange(1, 3)"* ... you have `inInclusiveRange(1, 7)`. And numbers 1, 2 and 3 are all between 1 and 7 inclusive.

Comment: I thought as much Gunter, but  inclusiveRange is not recognized - I think it is an error in naming the method.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Do you mean that the program throws an error?

Comment: @Juhana "inclusiveRange" is not a method or property name in the test package currently, by error it is inInclusiveRange - please check the package for clarification.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're saying. What does that have to do with anything? Why do you want to use "inclusiveRange"?

Answer (score 0):

The test fails when you change the range for example like

```dart
expect(number, inInclusiveRange(1, 2));
```

because `3` **is** `>= 1` but **not** `<= 2`

Comment: Thanks Gunter - 1-3 would be in the range 1-7.